# delay tmux send-keys in vim function

Tags: vim, tmux

I have a shell script (lets name it `a.sh`) where I run a certain command. At some point this command needs user input.

I have setup a vim key binding where I run `a.sh` in a tmux session.

```
function! CreateTmux()
    !tmux has-session -t mysession || tmux new-session -d -s mysession
    !tmux send-keys -t mysession 'a.sh' Enter
    " This should be delayed by a few seconds
    !tmux send-keys -t mysession 'my choice' Enter
endfunction

nnoremap <F9> :call CreateTmux()<CR>
```

I would like to make a delayed `send-keys` through tmux to the session to input my choice for the prompt as well. Here is my code.

The limitations:
1. I hope to avoid blocking commands in vim so that I can continue working.
2. I can not edit a.sh so I can't make it pass without the prompt.
3. I don't have vim 8 and can't get it on the server that I am working on.

Comment: Would `:help sleep` help?

Comment: @romainl  as I said I don't want to block vim. Sleep is a vim command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try running the last tmux line in the background with a shell sleep. Replace the last line of the function with

```
!(sleep 4 && tmux send-keys -t mysession 'my choice' Enter)&
```

You would only need the `()` if you want to replace the `&&` by `;` for example.

Comment: Off course it is so simple when one has the answer :). Thank you. It works as I need it.